# I'm trying to understand just exactly how to use the cmd module

Tags: python, module, cmd

Let me preface this by saying: I'm a neophyte to Pyhon! I've written a bunch of modules to drive a user interactive application via the command line. Additionally, someone recommended that I look at using the cmd module. And I've looked at it on some sites, but still not sure how to use it. I don't have dyslexia or anything like that, but I have a really tough time digesting technical literature (with no examples) ... I'm a visual learner, and if I can see a good, clear example one time, it's with me for a life time. Can anyone give me a short intro on how to use the cmd module ...? Until then, I will continue to scour Google for good examples. I might get lucky ... Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at "argparse"? Imo it's easier to use and it's popular so there are many examples out there. http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doug Hellmann's [Python Module of the Week series](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/index.html) has [a good example of using the `cmd` module](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/cmd/).
Another good example is the [ActiveState recipe "Console built with Cmd object"](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/280500-console-built-with-cmd-object/), but I think it is more complicated. [ActiveState Python recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/) and [PyMOTW](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/index.html) are good sources for python examples.

You could also see the [`cmd` module's source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/cmd.py?view=markup) to understand how it works, and you may like the [`cmd2` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmd2/0.6.2) too.

Answer (score 3):

There was a very nice presentation by Catherine Devlin at last years PyCon about getting started with cmd and cmd2.

Video can be found on [pyvideo](http://pyvideo.org/video/306/pycon-2010--easy-command-line-applications-with-c).

Video, code and slides used to be on the [Pycon website](http://us.pycon.org/2010/conference/schedule/event/91/) but that link is now dead.